# Cross Midnight Hourly Loop PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I've spent so much time on trying to figure out how to create a loop that will echo time between given $start_time and $end_time incrementing it by one hour in format HH:MM. For example if i have $start_time = "22:00" and $end_time="04:00" the output should be like:

```
22:00

23:00

00:00

01:00

02:00

03:00

04:00
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! *I've spent so much time on trying to figure out*  could you add what you got so far ?

Comment: If you use the DateTime class, its built-in modify and add methods will handle that transition for you.

Comment: If you're just doing it numerically, `%` will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very elegant solution but you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$start_time = "22:00";
$end_time="04:00";

$timestamp = strtotime($start_time);
while(date('H:i', $timestamp) !== date('H:i', strtotime($end_time) + 60*60)){
    echo date('H:i', $timestamp) . "\n";
    $timestamp += 60*60;
}
```

With date function with 'H:i' parameter, you can compare only the hour part of the timestamp. That way the for loop will add an hour after every iteration until the variable has passed the end_time (that ensures you echoe the last time too).